# Issue getting Node.js Express 3.x template inheritance working with Swig via consolidate.js

Tags: node.js, templates, inheritance, express, swig

I can get 'standalone' templates to render just fine with this code, but I can't get template inheritance to work. Is there something I am overlooking or any other caveats anyone knows of?

Error: Circular extends found on line 3 of "... /views/index.html"!

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , http = require('http')

var app = express();

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.html', { header: 'Express' });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
});
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}<h1>{{ header }}</h1>{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Express{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this by setting `root` and `allowErrors` for `swig` itself:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , http = require('http')
  , swig = require('swig')

swig.init({ root: __dirname + '/views', allowErrors: true });

// ...
```

For more info, see [Using Swig with express.js](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#api-express) and [Swig API](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#api).

Comment: That did it! I kept searching the issues for the terms 'express' and 'inheritance', with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about swig, but in express3 they removed template inheritance, partials and layouts and left it up to the template engine to implement. There are plugins that might get it back for you.

ejs: https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals

https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials

Comment: According to the Swig docs, template inheritance is supported: https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/master/docs/inheritance.md

Comment: i tried, but i get a circular reference: Error: Circular extends found on line 2 of "/var/www/express-template-demo/demo/views/index.swig"

Comment: This might help, the example uses swig: https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js